# What perms does an app need to see the user's friends' wall posts just like the user would ?

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-wall

This seems like a fairly simple issue, however I could not find any straight answer to it, including in the FB permissions documentation page :-/

Anyway, here goes: I have an app that lets a user put up posts on their wall through it. What I need to do is display a list of posts that his/her friends have put up on their walls, and that are related to my app.

To put it in another way, when a user is connected to my app, I would like the app to see the user's friends' walls just like the user would see them. This would enable the app to browse those walls for relevant content.

There's a ton of friends permissions, all of which look very specific. The best bet would seem to me to be 'friends_likes'... only I'm not looking for likes, I'm simply after posts containing a link to my website that were intended to be seen by friends.

As I'm still not sure I'm being clear, here's a schematic view of the problem:

- user1 and user2 have both authorised my app to publish on their walls
- user1 and user2 are friends
- user2 has published a post on his/her wall, through my app, with visibility level set to "friends"

=> when user1 is connected to my app, I would like the app to display user2's post for him/her.

Any help on this would be immensely appreciated,

--
Guillaume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I'm still not sure I'm being clear, here's a schematic view of the
>   problem:
>
> ```
> user1 and user2 have both authorised my app to publish on their walls
> user1 and user2 are friends
> user2 has published a post on his/her wall, through my app, with visibility level set to "friends"
> ```
>
> => when user1 is connected to my app, I would like the app to display user2's post for him/her.

With those permissions and requirements, it will be fairly simple to get that list

FQL the stream table:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ This should get you started:

```
WHERE source_id IN (select uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) ' this is the getting stream items from friends
AND app_id = YOUR_APP_ID ' this is the thru your app part
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. You mean that I do not require any extra permission outside publish_stream for my app to be able to see posts from the user's friends ?
Although I thought so when I could not find any specific permission for feed posts (as opposed to 'likes' for instance, and the friends_likes perm), it just does not work : the posts do not show up. More precisely, the API call only retrieves public posts, not those intended for friends... do you see what I mean ?

Comment: `read_stream` is for HTTP GETs  `publish_stream` is for HTTP POSTs

Comment: Since the friend's post is already visible (per your requirements above) to the user of your app, then all you need is read_stream on the user.

Comment: I knew I was not being clear...
"Since the friend's post is already visible" => it is not, and that's precisely my issue.

The only visible posts are those that were published by friends with a confidentiality level set to "public".
Boy this is driving me nuts. Still, let me just say again that I do appreciate your help, even if my pb is not solved yet. It does soothe my soul a bit :-)

Comment: EDIT: looks like it's working now :-)

I experienced lots of trouble with the FB site today - apparently wasn't the only one - and it consistently messed up my debugging & test pages, leading me to false assumptions. Anyway, I'm happily accepting yuor answer, and am renewing my thanks to you.

Comment: Whew, I was worried about this because I have code in production that utilizes this type of search.  Glad it is working for you  :)